# Jasmine 3 errors in Angular 5.2 tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have some errors after running `ng test`, I got that after doing an upgrade to all my packages, here are the versions:

```
{
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
 ...
 "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
 }
```

and devDependencies

```
"jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~2.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0"
```

I got this error:

```
"message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]", "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]"
```

[image: karma screenshot]

All my tests are very simple like:

```
import { async, TestBed  } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { UserInmailComponent } from './user-inmail.component';

describe('Component: UserInmail', () => {
it('should create an instance', () => {
  const component = new UserInmailComponent();
  expect(component).toBeTruthy();
});
});
```

I don't think that my test files are causing the problem.

Comment: Can you provide your test file or files?

Comment: i have very simple tests, i have updated my question

Comment: Are you using a beforeEach or afterEach in your test?

Comment: no, i'm not using them, it's a new project , i haven't write much test only simple test as you can see

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also had trouble with this error message in several unit tests even with "jasmine-core v2.8.0". After some researching I was able to reproduce it and discovered that it happens when you use mocks or stubs that lack neccessary variables (in my case > observables).

So for example if you init your TestBed like this:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [HeaderComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule],
  providers: [
    {provide: AuthService, useClass: AuthServiceStub}
  ]
})
```

and you have an observable in AuthService which is somehow used inside your HeaderComponent but you forgot to define this observable inside your "AuthServiceStub" then it will lead to the 
**"An error was thrown in afterAll\n[object ErrorEvent]"** output.

It's a very confusing behavior of jasmine/karma because it doesn't give you any hint on what is going wrong. In my opinion it should throw a null-pointer exception because the attribute is not defined inside the stub.

Answer (score 1):

it's related to a bug in zone.js
you have to downgrade jasmine version to 2.9 to make it work

```
"jasmine-core": "~2.9.0",
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research, this seems like a very broad error that can come about from many developer errors. 
My specific error was making a call to HttpClient (HttpClientTestingModule) with a url that was undefined. The error was relatively supressed in my browser and once i fixed it, the test run passes every time now. I've spent two days on this pulling my hair out, but all i needed to do was jasmine spyOn.and.callThrough() instead of just using spyOn